# Is there any way to auto merge a TFS baseless merge?

Tags: tfs, merge

This is TFS 2008.

The trunk was renamed and we now need to merge a great^6 grand child of the trunk back into it.  We are only able to do a baseless merge.  When a baseless merge was done there were 13,000 conflicts.  Auto-merge was then tried and it only reduced the conflicts by 1,000.  The majority of these files are identical.  I was wondering if there was any way to get TFS or visual studio to do a more aggressive auto merge based on file content.

If this is not an option through TFS any thoughts on how to do something similar through a powershell script or the TFS SDK would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the trunk back to its original name, and the merge will cease to be "baseless."

Yes, I hear you, that is *beyond stupid* but it works.  I don't make this stuff up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice this saved me hours of time.  I thought about this but dismissed the idea.